# How to plot datasets 1 factors for K mean clustering python

Tags: python, dataset, clustering, pandas, k-means

I'm unable to plot the data for K mean clusering algo usingsklearn as it throws this error : *TypeError: scatter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'*

Here is the function I have written to plot my clusters:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn import datasets
data=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/dataforclustering1.csv')
df=data

#KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(df)
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
print(centroids)
```

[image: output]

After I write plot k mean:

```
plt.scatter(df, c= kmeans.labels_.astype(float), s=50, alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], c='red', s=50)
```

[image: **Output**]

What is the best way to plot clusters in python?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be explicit on what is the x axis in the plot, and what attribute is the y axis. You are only passing the entire data frame - pass two columns instead.